# Store the values without overwriting

Tags: java, hashmap, keyvaluepair

I have a `Map<String, Integer>` e.g.

1. `"aaa", 1`
2. `"bbb", 2`
3. `"ccc", 3`
4. `"aaa", 4`

The problem is that the `HashMap` does not store all key and values, as I've understood, when i try add the last pair `("aaa", 4)`, it will not be added, instead of this, the value for `"aaa"` (I mean 1) will be overwritten on 4.

I know, that I could create class, where I could store these pairs, but I need another solution. (without creating a new class)

EDIT ------------------------------------
Actually I have much more pairs, and I do not have uniques String or Integers, I mean that, if even I have two similar pairs  they will be stored

Comment: Have a look at MultiMap

Comment: Why you doesn't use a Map<String, List<Integer>> ? Or Apache Commons / Guava MultiMap ?

Comment: If Integer is unique, you can use `<Integer, String>`

Comment: Could also go for List<Pair<String, Integer>>

Comment: I wish for the day when we'd have multi map in java core collection.

Comment: Actually, this list contains much more elements, where I want to store every pair, even if this pair already exists (I want to have a both in list, hashmap or somewhere else :) besides the class

Answer (score 1):

A map, by definition, will have distinct keys. If you add a key-value pair and the key already exists, the new key-value pair will overwrite the existing key-value pair.

For your scenario, when you have multiple values against a single key, you can explore the following options

Option 1 : Since your key-value pairs are not unique, it can be stored as list of [pairs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html). For every key-value pair, you can create a pair and insert it into the list.

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> data = new ArrayList();
Pair<String, Integer> item = new Pair("abc", 1);
data.add(item);
```

This option does not give you optimized lookup capabilities that comes with Map.

Option 2. Create a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`. You'll not be able to do simple put operations on the map anymore, but you will be able to store all the items corresponding to each key without loss of information as well as retrieve them faster.

Answer (score 0):

Create a List:

```
if (!map.containsKey("aaaa")) {
  map.put("aaaa", new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
List<Integer> aaaaValues = map.get("aaaa");
aaaaValues.add(1);
aaaaValues.add(4);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are unieque, use them as keys.
You don't have to create class. You can use `List<org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair<String, Integer>>`

Also one way, override equals and hashCode where you speak that object is unique only if String and Integer parameter is unique in pair

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){
            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o)
            {
                // your realization
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode()
            {
                // your realization
            }
        };
```